# INSERT problems with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, data-structures, sql-insert

I am using netbeans and trying to insert a new property address to the database, which works. My add Renter does NOT can someone help me please.

```
String addAddress = txtAddAddress.getText();
            String addRentAmt = txtAddAmt.getText();

            Statement lstatement = conn.createStatement();

            ls_query = "INSERT INTO Property(Address,RentAmt) "
            + "VALUES ('" + addAddress + "'," + addRentAmt + ")";
        System.out.println(ls_query);
```

**But I need it inserted as an addressID in my renter table as well.**

here is my sql code so you may see the structure of my 2 tables.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Property` (
  `AddressID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `RentAmt` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Address` (`Address`),
  KEY `Address_2` (`Address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Renter` (
  `RenterID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AddressID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `CellPhone` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000-000-0000',
  `DepositPaid` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `DepositAmtPaid` decimal(6,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RenterID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `AddressID` (`AddressID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**here is my insert statement to add a renter**

```
String addFirstName = txtFirstName.getText();
String addAddress = txtShowAddress.getText();
String addLastName = txtLastName.getText();
String addCellPhone = txtCellPhone.getText();
String addDepositAmtPaid = txtDepositAmtPaid.getText();
Statement lstatement = conn.createStatement();

ls_query = "INSERT INTO Renter 
(FirstName,LastName,CellPhone,DepositPaid,DepositAmtPaid) "
                        + "VALUES('" 
                        + addFirstName + "','" 
                        + addLastName + "','" 
                        + addCellPhone + "','" 
                        + addDepositPaid + "'," 
                        + addDepositAmtPaid + ","
                     + "' WHERE RenterID = '" + addressID + "'" ;
```

***But it doesnt work***

Comment: If you put the address in the Renter table (which is a bad idea), it is deleted when you delete the renter. Makes sense, right?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7b31

Answer (score 0):

I think a better design would be to keep the address info where it makes sense - the Property table.

Think about what you want to represent, without worrying about tables.

Can a Property be rented by more than one Renter at a time?  Does your design permit roommates?

Do you want to preserve history?  Can a Renter move several times and rent more than one Property?

Can a Renter have more than one lease simultaneously?  Can you rent for living and business?

All these questions should have you thinking about cardinality.

The foreign key goes in the many table in a one-to-many relationship.

If you have many-to-many, you'll need a JOIN table with two foreign keys.

Comment: This is for small property management, a total of 17 rental apartments, and renters. All I want to do is add/delete renters to each property address, and keep track if they paid a deposit and the amount, for now anyways. I am going to edit my question again because when I exported my database & tables it looks different than what I posted.

Comment: None of this changes the fact that the property address belongs in the property table.  Don't let your lack of facility with relational design compromise the reality of the system you'd like to model.